# url rewriting hide folder name from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm trying to rewrite my url but still not get success. I googled since two days but no success. I'm pasting my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L]
```

This is my directory:

```
localhost/project/index.php
```

in this page there are two button. if button one clicked, it should redirect to folder1/index.php else if button two clicked then it should redirect folder2/index.php

```
localhost/project/folder1/index.php
localhost/project/folder2/index.php

Basically I don't want display folder1 or folder2 directory names.
any idea please thanks
```

actuall url that i want to display should look like:
localhost/project/

Comment: You need to tell us what URL you would like each folder to appear as. You will need to differentiate between the two folders in some way.

Comment: actuall url that i want to display should look like:  
localhost/project/

Comment: ok, and the filenames? localhost/project/folder1 and localhost/project/folder2 or what? You cant make localhost/project refer to two different locations.

Comment: You may be able to set a cookie (folder1||folder2) on click. Have /project/index.php check cookie and include('folderX/index.php'); :shrug: good luck

Comment: @DavidHoude i'm already using cookie for this but i want url rewriting and don't want to show (folder1|folder2). but it should access (folder1/index.php|folder2/index.php) but url should be look like this:  
http://localhost/project/index.php

Comment: Please read my question again i think i'd explain quit well... thanx :)

Comment: Okay, I will post an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will be able to do what you are requesting with mod_rewrite alone.

The problem is you are trying to rewrite 1 file to 2 separate locations:

```
/project/index.php -> /project/folder1/index.php
/project/index.php -> /project/folder2/index.php
```

With this logic, mod_rewrite does not know what link your client clicked on, folder1 or folder2.

In order to achieve what you are looking for, you will need to set a cookie on the client indicating his choice of 'folders' -- then use PHP to determine the best action. Here is an example to give you an idea. This code isn't production ready.

**/project/index.php:**

```
$cookie_folder = $_COOKIE['folder'];
if($cookie_folder == "folder1")     { $folder = 'folder1'; }
elseif($cookie_folder == "folder2") { $folder = 'folder2'; }
require_once('/absolute/path/to/project/' . $folder . '/index.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume what you want is for the browser to request /index.php but the server to actually use the file located at /folder1/index.php, right? If so, this should work:

Make sure the apache mod_rewrite module is installed. Then, use something like this in your apache config, virtual host config, or .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /folder1/$1
```

The rules use regular expressions, so you may want to look at a reference on that topic if you're unsure. Read the manual for more info on other directives (RewriteCond can be very useful) or rule options.

Comment: i've already use this rule in my code you can see last line rule please.